# Cookie data won't display

Tags: php, cookies

Been tinkering with some code from github to make a user login area and such (something I've not done much of). I've got it all working, except the bit that shows your username after a user has logged in.

I decided the best way was to display the username cookie. When printing all cookies, it comes up (along with the password) but it won't come up when I asked it to display the username cookie. Anyhow, this is what I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The bit of code that sets the cookies. I think this could be the problem and may need rewriting, although, like I say, it does set the cookies:

```
$_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
$hour = time() + 3600; 
setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 
setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);
```

Bit that displays (or supposed to display) The current logged in user and a logout button:

```
echo "Welcome,";
echo $_COOKIE['username'];


 echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";
```

Comment: Shouldn't you echo `$_COOKIE[ID_my_site]` if the value of the cookie is the user name? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are `*_my_*` defined variables?

Comment: Literally just kicking myself oh dear, thank you.

Comment: Jay was right, lack of sleep has made me forget everything :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format of setcookie function is like this: 
**setcookie('cookie name','cookie value', 'expire');**
In your case the cookie name will be ID_my_site and Key_my_site. 
**so echo $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'] and echo $_COOKIE['Key_my_site']**......